# Access to API's

Tags: php, json, api, soap, wsdl

I have a web-service.
I try to create a Soap Client in php like this:

```
<?php
  $client = new SoapClient("link.svc?wsdl",array("trace"=>1,"exceptions"=>0));
  print_r($client);

  $parameters = array("request"=>array("function" => "request1"));
  $values = $client->FindSomething($parameters);
  print_r($values);
?>
```

and then use std_Object Class.

I try in this way, but I know there are other ways to create a client and obtain data (eg. in Json Rest).

This is the first time I do this. If someone already has experience, can give me an example of request (in json or php, does not matter)? Thank you in advance!